# Thumbnails Not Generating

Tags: custom-post-types, post-thumbnails, images

Ok,

So this is a weird issue...WordPress doesn't generate thumbnails, I have my image sizes set and everything...I'm pretty sure it's related to my custom posts type code (see below) because when I remove it the thumbnails generate properly.

```
// Tells WP to add a slides and marquee sections
add_action( 'init', 'create_my_post_types' );

// WP slides section attributes
function create_my_post_types() {
    // Add Slide Section
    register_post_type( 'slides',
        array(
            'exclude_from_search' => true,
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Slides' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Slides' ),
                'search_items' => __('Search Slides'),
            ),
                    'public' => true,
                    'publicly_queryable' => true,
                    'show_ui' => true,
                    'query_var' => true,
                    'rewrite' => true,
                    'capability_type' => 'post',
                    'hierarchical' => false,
                    'menu_position' => 5,
                    'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail')
        )
    );
    // Add Marquee Section
    register_post_type( 'marquee',
        array(
            'exclude_from_search' => true,
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Marquee' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Marquee' ),
                'search_items' => __('Search Marquee'),
            ),
                    'public' => true,
                    'publicly_queryable' => true,
                    'show_ui' => true,
                    'query_var' => true,
                    'rewrite' => true,
                    'capability_type' => 'post',
                    'hierarchical' => false,
                    'menu_position' => 6,
                    'supports' => array('title','editor')
        )
    );
}
```

Anyone see what's wrong with the code or know why this code would interfere with normal thumbnail generation?

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: Did you resolve this? Please share the solution if so.

Answer (score 1):

In your custom post type slides you have provided support for thumbnail and When you use custom post type that use thumbnails remember to check that the theme also supports thumbnails or use [add_theme_support](http://codex.wordpress.org/add_theme_support) function.

For more information see the supports parameter on [this page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type).

Comment: Vinod...as I mentioned in my original post, I have added theme support and it's still not working properly...the code I am using for the thumbnails looks like: http://pastebin.com/t1s9cbLN. Also, this issue doesn't just affect my custom post type, but all thumbnails in-general :(

Comment: I downloaded and installed http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-maker/ which is a plugin that creates the custom post types for you and I still have the same issue, even after removing my code for the custom post types...which makes me wonder where the conflict resides, because it's obviously with the post types themselves and not the code. If the plugin is activated the thumbnails fail to generate...if I deactivate the plugin everything works fine.

Comment: Ok, so I applied the Twenty Twelve theme, just to see what would happen and the thumbnails generate...so now we know something is wrong with my functions file. I took a look at how post thumbnails are added and mine looks like: `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post','slides' ) );` where Twenty Twelve looks like: `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );`...so I simply deleted the array at the end...but that still didn't work! I'm not sure where to go or what to check from here.

Comment: Are you adding theme support at the same point as twentytwelve? That is, directly into functions.php or within a function attached to the 'after_setup_theme' hook?

Comment: I am adding it directly to `functions.php`...I have done several other themes, none of which have this problem but none of the other ones are using custom post types.

Comment: Making progress...just to test I removed all of my custom image sizes (`add_image_size`) and my thumbnails are generating properly again...any clue why this could create a conflict? I copied that code from another working website that doesn't have any issues.

Comment: I dont see anything wrong with your CPTs. And you say that purely removing the CPT code 'fixes' the thumbnail issue?

Comment: It goes away if I remove all of my custom image sizes (`add_image_size`) or if I deactivate my custom post type plugin.

Comment: Getting closer...you can see my code at: http://pastebin.com/t1s9cbLN (the array was removed on line 2). Also, the thumbnails get generated if I remove the `add_image_size` `admin-thumbnail` and `post-thumb` but I have no idea why.

Comment: Ok, so this was not a sizing issue as I initially thought...it seems if there are more than 3 images (including the default) it doesn't generate thumbnails, but if I have 3 or less it does...any ideas what might cause that?

Comment: I ran your code on a sandbox install and it worked fine. The image you are uploading is big enough to accommodate the custom sizes, right? Because WP won't create bigger versions.

Comment: Yes...to test, I am using two images that are both wallpapers, that way I can tell if it works or doesn't work...like I said I am pretty sure it related to the amount of thumbnails being generated, not the size.